# Display picture in a certain folder, iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, gallery, image

is there any way to display pictures from a certain folder using iPhone default libraries?
I'll try to explain my problem:

WHAT I HAVE:
I have a view with a text description and I want to display images by clicking a button.

(i'll try to draw my view)

```
    ____________________________
   /                            \
   |        °==========         |
   |                            |
   |____________________________|
   ||       NAVIGATION BAR     ||
   ||__________________________||
   ||                          ||
   ||  ______________________  ||
   ||  |                    |  ||
   ||  |                    |  ||
   ||  |                    |  ||
   ||  |   TEXT BOX SPACE   |  ||
   ||  |                    |  ||
   ||  |                    |  ||
   ||  |                    |  ||
   ||  |                    |  ||
   ||  ----------------------  ||
   ||                          ||
   ||     ________________     ||
   ||     | Image button |     ||
   ||     ----------------     ||
   ||__________________________||
   |              _             |
   |             / \            |
   |             \_/            |
   \____________________________/
```

UPDATE:
Image:
[image: http://img851.imageshack.us/img851/8229/schermata022455966alle1.png]

WHERE I WANT TO ARRIVE:

I have a folder in the the app directory (example   /Images/ )
with an undefined number of pictures.

I would like to:
1) Display all the pictures in the folder, using the slide to pass from one to another (similar to the iPhone gallery)

or

2) Display the list of the pictures or the files in the folder and select the one I want to see.

And after viewing the images, go back to the description page.

Is it possible to do that?

***UPDATE***

Alternative Way:

Supposed I can obtain an array of images.
Do you think it would be possible to Load into a Uiimageview an image, and "refreshing" it by using buttons?
Something like this

[image: http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/1016/schermata022455967alle1.png]

Comment: Yes it is possible, I recommend using the NSFileManager for file manipulation - this includes traversing all files in a given directory for reading, as you need.

Comment: BTW - You know that you can attach images to your post, right? :)

Comment: ahah yes I know, but i have xcode and the project in another computer, so i cannot make a screenshot.

Comment: Oh okay. This may also come in handy: http://www.lucidchart.com/pages/examples/iphone_mockup_tool

Comment: You are welcome. I am posting it is an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than NSFileManager you can just use:

```
NSArray *files = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"jpeg" inDirectory:@"theFolder"];
```

Obviously building the swipable gallery to actually display the images is a lot more work. I suggest trying my [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) library, which won't do all the work for you, but basically provides something like a horizontal tableview, to make it much simpler. If you set the item spacing to match the screen width, and make each carousel screen-sized, it should do what you want.

You'd also have the option of displaying the images with CoverFlow instead of just a flat carousel if you want ;-)

**Update:**

You can certainly set the UIImageView image property using buttons. Create an IBOutlet for the image view and IBActions for each of your buttons, then just put this code in the action (I'm assuming you've loaded your image filenames and stored them in an array property called imagePaths, and that you have another string property called currentImagePath):

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *imagePaths;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *currentImagePath;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

- (IBAction)previousImageButtonAction
{
    NSInteger index = [imagePaths indexOfObject:currentImagePath];
    if (index == NSNotFound) index = 0;
    index = ((index - 1) + [imagePaths count]) % [imagePaths count];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imagePaths objectAtIndex:index]];
    imageView.image = image;
}

- (IBAction)nextImageButtonAction
{
    NSInteger index = [imagePaths indexOfObject:currentImagePath];
    if (index == NSNotFound) index = 0;
    index = (index + 1) % [imagePaths count];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imagePaths objectAtIndex:index]];
    imageView.image = image;
}
```

If you hook everything up correctly, the buttons will now cycle the images in the main image view. If you reach the last image it will wrap around automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your help with the pictures array.I've updated the question